# Seven sins, seven Wizards, seven symbols, seven times repeated, but six super-heroes

Tags: analysis, dc-extended-universe, shazam

Throughout Shazam!, we see many references to the number 7.

> Wizard: My job is to protect you
>   the seven worlds of the seven main sins.
>
> Sivana: That seven symbols. Total seven times repeated.
>
> Wizard: The Seven Wizards, Seven Thrones.

But at the end, Shazam! splits his power with his 5 siblings, and we have a total of six heroes. I half expected an additional hero to show up, or some way of having seven heroes to battle the seven sins. This could mean Billy had all the powers, and each other hero specialized in a specific aspect (similar to what we saw, one had lightning, other had speed, etc).

**Does the number 7 have a deeper meaning in the Shazam universe? Will a 7th hero be found?** Or was this just something based on the 7 deadly sins, and 6 super-heroes was just randomly based on the amount of kids in the foster family?

Comment: I imagine there're only six champions that we see in the movie because the seventh champion is already out there: Black Adam.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's like that in comics too in current version:

> The Shazam Family was reintroduced during DC Comics' continuity-altering Flashpoint miniseries in 2011, as six kids who all spoke "Shazam!" in unison to become one superhero, Captain Thunder. In the later company-wide "New 52" reboot that followed Flashpoint, the Captain Marvel character was renamed "Shazam" and starred in a backup segment of the Justice League series (second volume) from 2012 to 2013. These backups, by writer Geoff Johns and artist Gary Frank, introduced Billy Batson/Shazam and his new Shazam Family, consisting of Billy and his five foster siblings, with whom he shares his powers. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Family)
>
> [image]

In comics, 6 was the max member of Marvel/Shazam family at a time.

And also not everything is seven, SHAZAM is 6 letter and he gets the power of 6 gods:

> the wisdom of Solomon, granting increased intellect; the superhuman strength of Hercules, the superhuman stamina of Atlas; powers from Zeus, including the ability to summon lightning; the increased courage of Achilles, as well as being nearly indestructible; and the superhuman speed of Mercury, which provides him with the means of flight.

Comment: Six kids form 1 hero, _making seven_ (which also works for the number of gods. Plus isn't it "shazam!"? The exclamation point makes seven.

Comment: There is a significant chance that Black Adam is number 7. Using mainly the movie as a reference (and his latest comic origin) Black Adam probably got his powers from Shazaam, so it's likely given the wizard council and the history lesson about the champion that turned on the wizards to release the sins, combined with the upcoming Black Adam film that he is the 7th and still around since his betrayal.

Comment: @Duffy in comics black Adam also had his own marvel/Shazam competitor family so I doubt he will join Shazam family like this and he is more of anti hero not hero even in comics yet

Comment: @Bilkokuya do the wizards turn into one unique individual? I haven't seen the movie, but from my understanding, the 6 kids actually TURN into a seventh person, not a group (shazam!). If that's incorrect, then just ignore me

Comment: @Bilkokuya i guess my thought on that gods part is that 6 powers united is kind of like a unique seventh power. But yeah, that's a stretch

Comment: @Ankit Based on the movie I suspect that is where they are going with it in the movie universe and there is some correlation based on the latest origin reboot for Shazaam and Black Adam. Six vs Seven seems too obvious an oddity (and change to the mythos), maybe it won't be but it would fill in the gap if he was considered the 7th. His status as a villian/anti hero doesn't negate the source of his power being the wizard council. But I digress.

Comment: @Aethenosity Thanks for explaining, that makes a lot of sense - removed my initial comment. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Solomon is a god in the DCU?  I thought he was just a king.  A wise king, sure, but not a deity.  Especially since the religions he is typically associated with are monotheistic.  I mean, technically neither Hercules or Achilles are gods either (demigods at best), but I don't know how much DC cares about the actual mythology behind them...

Comment: “not everything is seven” — true, but the original Council of Wizards as shown in the movie had seven members, hence seven seats for them on the Rock of Eternity.

Comment: I believe Billy Batson’s biological father is the seventh member of the Shazam family in the comics now. That said, I thought each of the seven kids seemed to have some slight affinity with/preference toward one of the six powers.